# Removing items from store without using filter

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to remove the fields from accordion list, if its not match with my searchfield name only actual search name should be shown in list. Search functionality working fine. But i cant remove rest of elements from the store. Duplicate occurs

```
 for (var j = length; j--;)
    {
    console.log(store.data.items[j]);
    console.log(store.data.items[j].data.testname);
    //store.clearFilter(true);
       if (store.data.items[j].data.testname.search(new RegExp(searchfield, "i")) === -1) 
       {
        //store.filter('testname',store.data.items[j].data.testname);
          store.data.items[j].remove();
        }
    }
```

Output - Type **Mango**

- Mango
- Apple   --> Unwanted
- Banana  --> Unwanted
- Mango --> Duplicate

Expected

- Mango ---> Actual search

Or

- Mango
- Apple
- Banana

Any suggestion.

Comment: What is "testname" in if (store.data.items[j].data.testname.search(new RegExp(searchfield, "i")) === -1)? Will appreciate ur reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
store.removeAt(j);
```

You want to remove a record and not only the data.
But if you want to remove it only for some time you might want to use

```
store.filterBy(function() {
    your Code
    return true only for those you need and false for those unwanted ones
})
```